# Identifying strange Perl CGI script

Tags: reverse-engineering, perl

Recently, while looking at some Perl CGI files, I came across this. I am not familiar enough with Perl to know exactly what it means, but I did attempt to base64 decode the string to no effect. Can anyone tell me what this is doing or what it means?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require './lib.pl';OFND('JmJhJÊ3ÝeWlpµTÞAKCk7ÇVBÖDQpp6OZ2ZiAo1VEJJEVOÇFNOVntS3M14RVFVQÞðGRVNUUçB¼X01FÇ5ÖQVEhP1DÇ9RH0gPëLïZXEgÝÝMJIlBPJQKµU1QiÖïAAKSB7ERQøICZSOCM7ZWFkµÐÿLUGFyçNQöc2VNFJIðaW1lÿµ3EKCk7OïVÑIH0NU²D¼CmVs£2USc2UgãLÿ5eyAmëN8²UmVhÐþü1ZFBhçÿ5McnNl²ãDÑKCk7üºý5ICRuZë14b191£ÐIUcGxvWü9HYWQgGMDÝPSAxVý2¼OyB9NWøüDQppð¼Z5Zigk¼GüXaW579üµQJ3JlGOÇýbW90MQLUZWZpýN3YbGUn9AÖ£fSl7ÞÞX7DQomÞïµøbGlzH8ÿFdF9jÞãCÝb21tEºV9YW5kEMKWKCJtB2×BdWx0ÿã¼ÑaWNjZWTVY2Ftø3ÊRIiwkÝ¿86bXVsöþÿïdGljøCµ3Y2NhüLFObSk7PÝçVDQoJ1¿VJQGV4Bþ9JcHMg4ý×HPSAm£2USbGlzëÝMFdF9lÇ5ÖQeHBv0QBEcnRzXTüJKCk7×F0KDQoJ£ýµãJGV4µHMHcCA9RTM5ICRlKNþ7eHBzBIWýWyRp40ÑVbnsn065AaWR4VÐ03J31dÑÝQ¼Ow0K4F80CSVvXFOBcHRzµ5ïëID0gLH7XJXskY4Ö3ZXhwþ02LLT57£²6PJ29wNDOÞdGlvFOCTbnMn²çøÝfX07JüºÝDQogçJO3ICAgHÖHCJG11V¼ý5bHRpÞVUëY2ZnFGAXID0g£VGüIiRløöEüeHAt8¼ÜAPnsnº£ZYaG9zV×TþdCd9öë0ÞXyRlH¿CCeHAtA¿3×PnsnCµ0CcG9yHPO×dCd9öðÖYXyRlVý2¼eHAtQçMKPnsnOïVÑbW9kJF²XdWwnýN3YfS5jÇLã5ZmciZHÞÐOw0KWÝC6ICAgRüÿ2ICRyAX7JZW1v7XPRdGVmJFöXaWxlþÐTUPSAiÞÊJçL3RtUNHYcC8kO042bXVsºGK3dGlj8TH3Zmci7ÜJ7Ow0K²LÝ²ICAgþÑVUICRw3ÞNSYWdl7A²NID0gøDGÖIi8iNÜÿULiRlFGAXeHAtãOÇZPnsnQ2×QbW9kQÐEVdWwnð6¿LfS4iµ0µUL3Jl9MøÊbW90ðÞþ9ZS5jµ¿J²Z2k/29øëZG93ÐZKDbmxvëDZAYWQ9þ1T¿MSI77XLPDQogÜöDXICAgGA46aHR01üü×cF9kÜöDXb3duüãµºbG9hÿã¼ÑZCgkF£C9ZXhwÜï7ðLT57¼R8UJ2hv×ME6c3QnöDãïfSwgRC×KJGV4UBWZcC0+667ºeydw7ÝUöb3J0IÊüQJ30s3IACICRwKTýOYWdlNKNãLCBcT6¿1JGRfÝY8AbWx0KAÜTY3MsJýÇïIFwkAX7JZXJyWPQDZCwg3ö7ëMCwg9ZÞøJGV4ÝÿYHcC0+Ð4SÞeydzºëU¼c2wnÐºHNfSwgVý2¼JGV4LXðLcC0+Ç8B£eyd18²4Sc2Vy8OöIJ30sZ7ö0JGV4U²D¼cC0+VEVYeydwëÝMFYXNzZKþVJ30sÖ¼IEICRj²Qÿ²b25mÇKç3aWd77L38J211¿RDHbHRpøþÑZY2NjV¿ÐºYW1fKµµQdGltR6º3ZW91ÞãCÝdCd9DÇø3KTsN£ÑPÿCiRl07ðýcnJkÝ4MµID8g2¼1SJmVyÖý¿¼cm9yýÜTRKCR0KNþ7ZXh0C5XVeydoKµµQYXRhµHMHJ30uIÊÇøJGVyMZBçcmQuY4Ö3IjxiÖø63cj4kVÐ03ZXhwI7Ñ2LT57ÐM64J2hvX¿2Bc3QnAINDfTokS5¿üZXhwÇC56LT57¿8QºJ3BvÝÇï8cnQnç1çOfSAkÇÞ9OdGV4J9PHdHsnGKY0c2VyëÝMFdmVyºQµIX3Nh9MøÊdmVf7XPRY29uERüÞbmVjCIÐYdCd9DKZÞIikgZÝ9ROiB1Ý1ëÖbmRlÊLH²ZjsNRNµWCiZj33K0cmVhÝÞC²dGVmVýµ£aWxlV04SKCRyM1¿ÞZW1vWÝC6dGVmSA0ÊaWxlüLFOLCRk7MGNX21sZHÞÐdGNz5ÞÇøLDEs2üOµMDc1FýAANSwpQÐEVOw0KÞüÜVJGZp30µ9bGUgQö8MPSAkJVL¼cmVt²MµÝb3RlURQLZmls0Ý9¿ZTsN7PKICn0gµJÝÝZWxzTGEAZSB7ÖPºFDQokMDV2ZmlsEMç¿ZSA9×1ºÝICRpHJUBbnsnTMKLZmlsðMNïZSd9ÞIº1Ow0KXÝÖLfQ0K2B0²bXkgÇ¿CøJGRpWÝö7ciA9çµÞYICIvã0MãdmFyA4RGL2V0ü8ÐÇYy8iºÊÞÿOw0KëV60QGZp1Ê7ÞbGVzÇ²B8ID0gUNY7KCAkHIºKY29uQ9üIZmlnKüÿEeydj8¼ÜAY2NhçJ²ÞbV9j8L¼TZmcnSï×YfSwNÇL×GCiAgGçÐ2ICAg×£ÜGICAgLH7XICAgGX7PJGRpH8ÿFci4i²8KGQ0Njç×ÇJYW0u¼øÖ0Y2hhöï0Qbm5l4R£YbGluJF²XZm8iOïVÑLA0KMÇÐÇICAgNÖÑGICAgYBÊMICAgÇöýHICAkA8Q8ZGlyCÊBYLiJDýUZGQ2NhG¼ACbS5wHÞ4ÖcmlvUï6BIiwN0ÐKNCiAgÖGRöICAg0ðMÞICAgXÝYÝICAgZNþÿJGRp9MC3ci4iKNSXQ0NjBGNHYW0uRÑDFcHJvüOEÿdmlk092üZXJzWü9HIiwN¼R8UCiAgçµÞYICAgAïGÖICAg75ïÜICAg9üµQJHR1ÜÝU6cmtkKNþ7dmIs3YTKDQog7çÖðICAgïB7¿ICAgÞýV×ICAg8OöIICRwX¿2BYWNrKçDUYWdlÊL²ELA0KçSXïICAgUçB¼ICAg5¼QµICAgVEFHICAkAVþ4a2V5C5XVcywNZHJTCiAgT6¿1ICAgF8øKICAgZ¿CÜICAgÑAUVJGJh²µMEeWlfJëCEZG9jýUçDLA0Kð7£üICAgCöçUICAgIÐ6ºICAg²Bç8ICAkW52ZdXNlZZÝFcnNfKÞðWZGVsÐK7UZXRlJPÑ¼ZCwNPMKRCiAgBþ9JICAg1X65ICAgÑ5ëÇICAgÞïµøJG11ðYQKbHRpEW8¿Y2NjöUCMYW0s2NøXDQogçJ²ÞICAgµ4WðICAgãÑöKICAgGWÑµICRk×£ÜGeW5fMXÖYZmlsçRÜÊZSwNL2ÞðCiAg1ÞZçICAgÞýV×ICAgº×RVICAgÜMµÖJHJlEëBÐbW90YOFNZWZpEW8¿bGUpOLÿROw0KÐ0Z6JGZpNÖÑGbGUgÖï3öPSAk89ÖüZmls¿ý0RZXNbGOBBMF0gTDNüaWYgSA0ÊKCEkX9ýVZmlsCVJÖZSk7²þÖ¿DQpm8ÇÝMb3JlVøYWYWNoMþëKICRmXFOBIChAR¿7ðZmlsÊL²EZXMpÊðKçIHsNºÇÝüCgkJµTÞAJGYgÿ4P1ZXEg2µIøJGZpAINDbGUgEëBÐPyAnÖüÿUc2VsNDOÞZWN07TNAZWQn63¿CIDogüLFOJycsïÝZMICRmFüÜ¿Ow0Kïµ£XCSRmEJçQb3VuBB¿ïZCsrFµYJIGlmÑAUVICgkÐ2ÿÑZiBl2ëÞ×cSAkÞ¿3²Zmls0EHÖZSk7T6¿1DQoJAãAUfQ0KPP12IyMjÇC56IyMjAãçUIyMjð2£7IyMj2NøXIyMjN8E4IyMjýJQÇIyMjÜÇ¼3IyMjëüB4IyMj²µMEIyMjLÊJºIyMjµYVHIyMjµYVHIyMjþIJºIyMj9ÿöýIyMjÖÞÐçIyMjçðÐµIyMjXJöÐIyMjïðýÞIyMjWïJðIyMjÝÝPºIyMjÿãøRIyMjAãAUIyMj²XðBIyMjÖï3öIyMjFýAAIyMj¿öºHIyMjÖCýÿIyMjCø8ýIyMjþFWYIyMjA1ÑQIyMNYBÊMCmlmïðýÞKCEkC¼Q¿aW57Jë8ýJ2Zp¼5ï£bGVzçIëPYXZlMü6VJ30gVÞKºJiYg7ÝUöISRpºëU¼bnsnSQ6Zc2F2ýSSGZSd9ZMÐSKXsNIÝÝÑCiZj86ÿTY2Nh2ýMIbV9oAVþ4ZWFkãÑöKZXIoÊ2QZJHRl×OQðeHR7ç519J2FsÝÿIçbG1hDOK9bnVhGWÑµbF90KRÜWaXRsÿÊÐCZSd9ÇKç3KTsNüÐ4MCnByÇ5ÖQaW50BY²YICI8NG×ÞY2VuX9ð×dGVy¼R8UPiI7øN4²DQpwNKNãcmluÝÑ4FdCAkþFWYcmVtZNÞÞb3RlÖA7ãZmlsVÞKºZSA/ODÝLICZ0I7Ñ2ZHZiG24ÑZm9u39ðüdCgiãÝýýJHRlü8LüeHR7TMXÊJ211Q6ÇöbHRpIÊüQY2NjHSÇHYW1f²µEµdGl0µHMHbGUnÿF0GfSA9²µMEICIsTïëCNCwiBIF8Ymx1JWºLZSIsÝÇï8MSwiDþºýJGV4ç2çÿcC0+7SÞðeydoÇL×Gb3N089ÖüJ306¼ÖÑÐJGV4öþïHcC0+XÿºOeydwD4üRb3J0ýUçDJ30i38Ñ5LDQsZKþVInJlº¿ðµZCIsÖXCÜMSkg£5ý¼OiIi8L¼TOw0K87µGCXByZ¿CÜaW50ÇDQ4ICZ1DÜ×TaV9m2INüb3JtVø9SX3N0µ8¿¼YXJ00IÐÞKCJhZANÖbGxtBBFëYW51TÜµÞYWwuZFÐµY2dpIÞY×Iik7JVL¼DQokµÐÿLaW57¿ÞÜPJ3Jl£²6PbW90VBXRZWZpQÞµÑbGUnÜNR4fSA/EC²ÐCXBy5Ð×ãaW50ðÜµ9ICZ1ðÜµ9aV9o¼CÑMaWRk1OM0ZW4oXÝÖLImlkQUð9eCIsÞ3µºICRpQ9Ü²bnsnÖR6HaWR4Üã¼PJ30pÞIº1LCJc2¼ÊJbiI6öþïHJyc7ðYQKDQokSWZ¿aW572LW×J3JlÑB87bW90ÿ4P1ZWZp×çDNbGUnY4Ö3fSA/LKDºCXBy4R£YaW50µHMHICZ138AºaV9oðNTöaWRkºK2ëZW4oGGINInJl8Ö3×bW90TDNüZWZpV¿IBbGUiÝEÜKLCAx04H9KSwiR¿º×XG4iþï×AOicnTX£5Ow0K7IBWJGluVIÊIeydyVEVYZW1vSYÐºdGVmN8E4aWxlÖï3öJ30gÑB87PwlwYFÜºcmluçýTÖdCAmÖï3ödWlfWX4LaGlkïÐ5PZGVuøëçþKCJpU²D¼bmRlAºN3eCIsIÞY×ICRpþFWYbnsnÝ4ÿFaW5kð¼Ð²ZXgnÜEÞTfSks4XPøIlxuPDWSIjon5£¼¿JzsN8OöICglwµKÖºcmluÝ4MµdCAmUR£RdWlfVSGýaGlkBIF8ZGVu¼PM9KCJpçýTÖZCIsGMDÝICRp¿WãSbnsn0Ý9¿aWQn8çÑðfSks3DGÜIlxuAMý2IjsNXðÑHCglw5Y7¼cmluGGINdCAkÑAUVdGV4ð2£7dHsnJQ6KYWxtV48RYW51X¿2BYWxsKAÜTX2No5ÞÇøZWNrÑÜFÑJ30sÝ59NIlxuïµÊÖIjsN87µGCgklç²º3aXNmQÞµÑZWF0R¿º×dXJlþ£üýID0g5UC×bWFw67Ý£IHsg×64ÑJF8süNJCIDEg4R£YfSBAGÝVQZmVhJ²NDdHVyKÜC2ZXM767Ý£DQoJNDOÞcHJpRðEðbnQgEºV9JnVp¿2ðLX3NlÿYKRbGVjþ¼NYdCgiBþ9JZmls5ç×OZSIsWÝö7ICRmöþÿïaWxlÊEMÐLCAkçÊFWcmVtCãNÞb3RlXÝYÝZmlsKÇöÞZSA/Ç126IFtb8ëPAJHJlYëëµbW906¼IDZWZpVøYWbGUsLVDGJG11YëëµbHRpÝ¿86Y2ZnãLÿ5XV0g5¼QµOg0KTïëCCQkgZMÐSWyBb×XHYJGNv£×A£bmZp85HSZ3snU²D¼Y2Nj¼TRðYW1f1AÿþY2Zn¿ãI¼J30söðJUIkNDXÊöüY2FtE4UÿLmNm7TNAZyJdAïGÖLA0K¿ýKWICAgMDV2ICAg2XÝ0ICAg596TICBb1L3ýJGRpLÊJºci4iÑK85Q0NjÿãøRYW0uSýçøcHJv1Ê7Þdmlk84µPZXJz¼R8UIiwiDI68Q0NjAãAUYW0uÇ²B8cHJvZLN7dmlkÜÇ¼3ZXJzRQGëIiAgÇöýHXSwNÞVü¿CiAgÜ6ÐZICAgK7FçICAgãENFICAg£µÿCWyRkT4U0aXIuLCQÿIkND75ïÜY2FtëÊüFLnByUP¿7aW8iÞJVºLCJDQNÞ8Q2NhYB23bS5wGÞÇðcmlvüNS6Il0sÿ6CHDQogTGEAICAgðýÖFICAgQ6CÿICAgÑÜFÑIFsk×þö1ZGlyG24ÑLiJD79FðQ2Nhð6¿LbS5jÜNR4aGFuI¼SKbmVs£A50aW5m84µPbyIsþUüRIkNDö²E×Y2FtR2²ÇLmNoFµYJYW5uJPÑ¼ZWxpöþïHbmZv5ç×OIl0sÿ£ÊNDQogÑCAGICAg×çDNICAgðZÝEICAgMÝU8IFsk2üOµdHVyïëCöa2R2ÊHC3YiAsÊEMÐIkv9¼GüXc/10IGORbP0gV48RUGFrPMKRZXRsH£ëEZXIiµ0F4XSwNA8Q8CiAgÿT²SICAgVEVYICAgN²Þ3ICAgÖ7P5WyRw67Ý£YWNrCÞø1YWdlÇ²×ïICwiSWJÞ1nplºK2ëbCBQ84µPYWtlºÇÝüdGxlDþºýciJd0EHÖLA0K2ëÞ×ICAgM30µICAgW5N×ICAgFÐ1XICBbºSÿýJGtlLºÑGeXMgV48RLCJLSJöþZXlzKÊGöIFVw¿WãSZGF0Ð25ÝZSJdïBEÞLA0K7SÞðICAgWPQDICAgÞRF9ICAgJýÇïICBbøÜ0ÞJGJh9VÜðeWlfBBFëZG9jKÝJ9ICwiëÊüFQmF5×ðþPaSBDYHµIb25m55ÿ5aWciSö0üXSwNþÐAXCiAgÿF0GICAg¿ZïþICAg²£ºøICAgLXðLWyR1AMý2c2VyR5G5c19kÿT²SZWxl¼ÖÑÐdGVkHÞ4ÖICwkN3øÇdGV4X¼ø¿dHsnÊçTçdXNlü8LücnNf9ÐÜ2ZGVsPZ6UZXRlÇUQÜZF90YPÖüaXRsE1DëZSd9A2NÞXSwNµOC8CiAg1²µNICAg6¼UºICAgÜüEµICAg3DGÜWyRtëÊüFdWx0IÞY×aWNj5SÇYY2Ft04H9LCJNÜNR4dWx0Ç5ÖQaUNDDþ1GY2FtLIëµIENvFüÜ¿bmZpTÜKÿZyJdçSXïLA0KY99PICAgQG7PICAg¼üÑÖICAgÿã¼ÑICBb2×QçJGR5H4Gðbl9mW6KÇaWxlERQøLCJE¼613eW4g£H4þQ29uIÿAVZmlnýLKVIl0N2QÊMCiAgëçFYICAgÝ¿ZÊICAgXµÞðICAgGWë5ICAgÖï3öICAgTYµDXSwxãRÿ8LCAwÞýV×LCAwDÇø3LCAw×Ñ¼KLCAiÐQÖMb25DÝÑ4FaGFu£2USZ2U9ºK2ëJ2Zv667ºcm0uBTZOc3ViøDGÖbWl0ÞVUëKCknJëCEIiApHÖHCOw0K£µÞSCXBy7XPRaW50XFOBICZ19MøÊaV9zÜ8ºÐdWJtR5NDaXQo£5ý¼JHRlµÊÊ4eHR7VøYWJ2FsãÝýýbWFuøDGÖdWFsKµµQbF9lXðçEZGl0I1ºXJ30p¼TOðOw0K¼IþDCXByÐM64aW50R¿7ðICImPDWSbmJzÞS8µcDsmWµçÇbmJzÇKç3cDtc66ëãbiI7R6º3DQoJTMKLcHJpWNþ£bnQgIÿAVJnVp88UQX2ZvWÝö7cm1fïWUÝZW5kçÿ5MKCk7×ÞD¼DQojïµÊÖIyMjWïJðIyMjHSÇHIyMjXý6×IyMj1²ë£IyMjÜã¼PIyMj6Oç2IyMjÜºIãIyMjHÝçUIyMjð4ÐþIyMjëðQWIyMjR2²ÇIyMjµKÖºIyMjÞïµøIyMjÝ4MµDQokøLÐFZm915Q9RbmQgPZ6UfHwg5OVWJmVyUüKRcm9yGOÇýKCR0öVPIZXh0Ç²B8eydtÜ8ºÐYW51öUCMYWxf¿öºHZWZpþ1T¿bGUnV¿ÐºfSk7ëÖ88DQpwZMøFcmluX¿2BdCAm1¿VJdWlføÜ0ÞZm9yö²E×bV9zKÝJ9dGFy8TH3dCgiAãçUYWxsRð1ZbWFuDOK9dWFsçCZ¼LmNnPÝçVaSIs0N60ICJmSï×Yb3Jt63¿CLWRhN8E4dGEiJÇ7BKTsNESA8CnByF£ÜÐaW50TïëCICZ19VM4aV9o0FëçaWRküFOQZW4oYHµIImZpSÿýðbGUiOÖþ5LCAkÝ2¿VZmlsëN8²ZSksïBEÞIlxuç0R6IjsNDI68CnByïOTëaW507ÑREICZ1¿öºHaV9oNÝþGaWRkÜX5ëZW4oð×IPImZp¿ÞÜPbGVzÊëµYYXZlLXðLIiwgKÞðWMSksQ9üIIlxu6ÿøºIjsN33K0CiRpAKãübnsn¿8QºcmVtø7¼þb3RlIÖUNZmlsVïOÐZSd9öY59ID8JLXðLcHJpöï0QbnQg²4Ö¼JnVpÿ4P1X2hpA¿3×ZGRlPQUýbigiBÐLQaWR4KNþÜIiwg3ÞNSJGluMÇÐÇeydpU2ÊFZHgnçë2ãfSksýVë2Ilxu¼CÑMIjonÐLLJJzsNHSÇHCiRpGOÇýbnsnEW8¿cmVt38Ñ5b3RlMXÖYZmlsãENFZSd9þÇøRID8J7çÖðcHJpÊðKçbnQgIÐ6ºJnVpNÐºÖX2hpI²WSZGRlBY²YbigiXÝYÝcmVt1Ê7Þb3RlO6SÝZmlsþUS6ZSIsÐÝÖÿIDEpFµYJLCJcýÇYµbiI6ÇVBÖJyc7ðVWºDQokëçFYaW570FëçJ3Jlã²üÑbW90ÇTKAZWZpÐºHNbGUn3Dö6fSA/MY¿çCXByÿ£ÊNaW50ÐºÿUICZ1KÊGöaV9oÜã¼PaWRkLÐNüZW4oVW7WImlu5ëÜDZGV4ANLIIiwgIð¿JJGluESA8eydp3¿4ÞbmRl9µ¼XeCd9BüµÐKSwi0KXYXG4iW¼A0Oicn67Ý£Ow0K2µIøJGRhÐTÊBdGEgÑ8MÑPSAmÝY8AcmVhOÖþ5ZF9m²Bç8aWxlÜÿÝ5X2NvGSº5bnRlÞïµøbnRzýN3YKCRmÇC56aWxlTüýãKTsN¿ö3ëCnByÊEMÐaW50ÇQ6KICZ1MQLUaV90PëLïZXh0KHD0YXJl85þ8YSgi×8Y6ZGF0ZÝ9RYSIsKøµGICRk×F0KYXRh£5ý¼LCAyEºV9NiwgJ4¿ÜMTEwÜEÞTLCAsJVGRIG9mãÝýýZiwgLÐNüdW5köVPIZWYs4PXZIHVuçë2ãZGVmÞð3VLA0KJ²NDCQkgBüµÐICAiüL8Öc3R5GOBBbGU9XÝYÝJ3dp¼CÑMZHRoFµYJOjEwO042MCUn0üVþIiksDMöQIjxi0Ý9¿cj5cSHFObiI7ýðIADQpwFµYJcmluÞ¿3²dCAm7PKIdWlfþIJºZm9yµ8¿¼bV9lJVGRbmQoçRÜÊWyBbZYAWICJz£ZMµYXZlÑÜFÑIiwg3Dö6JHRlLÐP5eHR7KÑãöJ3NhSÿýðdmUnUR£RfSBdÑK85IF0pBTZOOw0KµÊÊ4JnVpNÝÊCX3Byµ0F4aW50A¿3×X2Zv¼6ºÞb3RlM30µcigiGWÑµIiwg²MµÝJHRlüöW¿eHR7ý×LBJ2luÊº7ÊZGV46Oç2X3Jlç×NÜdHVy4ý×Hbid970ºÐKTsNNÝþGCnBy¿2ðLaW50ýQNWICI8XÊöüL2NlEC²ÐbnRl2QÊMcj4iSLHYOw0KãLÿ5fQ0KTMKLIyMjN09²IyMj9VM4IyMj£çÑ×IyMjZFÐµIyMjRÑDFIyMjPÑMKIyMj²ãDÑIyMjÜÇ¼3IyMjëV60IyMjÝ4MµIyMjþSë²IyMjO¼TÜIyMjÇVBÖIyMjëÖ88IyMjDÞÖÖIyMjB2ÇDIyMjÿãNöIyMjðYWHIyMj04ö4IyMjDSøAIyMjÞãCÝIyMjýQNWIyMjçSXïIyMjTÐö¿IyMjRAðQIyMjC5XVIyMjÐRÝ¿IyMj1üü×IyMjüÐ4MIyMjºÊÞÿIyMj9µ¼XIw0KXðY2aWYoçRÜ£JGlu×ºïøeydmA4RGaWxlÿþTïc2F2QçMKZSd9LQÜÖKXsN4XQøCiRpQMã8bnsnMÇÐÇZGF0£5ý¼YSd9¼PøBID1+UJ7ÿIHMvR8PPXHIvüTYCL2c7ø2PÑDQomÇ²×ïbG9jGKýÿa19mPQUýaWxlLKðHKCRpÊãACbnsnøþÑZZmlsµ0µUZSd9çµÞYKTsNýUZGCiZvÿ4P1cGVuµ0F4X3RlM4FÊbXBmJ5þ¼aWxl8çÑðKEZJÑÇL7TEUsýÇYµICI+7üø5JGluðOA¿eydmÿãøRaWxlB0ý6J30iQµESKTsNTDNüCiZwþIJºcmluQÐEVdF90LAA²ZW1wMü6VZmls×þö1ZShGN5FÐSUxFÿÊÐCLCAkþ£JNaW57øþÑZJ2RhB2×BdGEnIGORfSk7Z£çþDQom8L¼TY2xvÇVBÖc2Vf£çÑ×dGVtç9LÿcGZp×ÞD¼bGUoQEºHRklMUüKRRSk7µøVµDQomBÐLQdW5sÐÝÖÿb2NrSüFÜX2ZpIÐ6ºbGUoGWë5JGlu7ÐïÑeydmNDOÞaWxlAB8QJ30pBüµÐOw0K4ÿQ7aWYoÖÊ4ýJGluVBXReydyAA70ZW1vÑÐQödGVm2×QçaWxl0IÐÞJ30p3DGÜew0KþXQGICAgã4UÖICRyüJ²HZW1vPZ6UdGVmTÜµÞaWxlZRMUPSAiTUÖ4L3RtÞð3VcC8kX¼ø¿ZXhw¿8QºLT577çÖðJ2hvBIF8c3Qn7ÐPKfV8kSJöþZXhwZÝ9RLT57E8TYJ3BvF£C9cnQnVBXRfV8køÜ0ÞZXhwH4GðLT57DRN£J21v8TH3ZHVsVBXRJ30uZHÞÐY2ZnÖø63IjsNµÊÊ4CiAgýÜTRICAkKÑNPcGFnÖøISZSA9VïOÐICRl£ýÜþeHAtÖCº8PnsnöJ£SbW9kQüWOdWwnÑÐQöfS4i9ÐÜ2L3JlAF¼SbW903ö7ëZS5jýQT8Z2k/ëMUÊdXBs¼TRðb2FkI¼SKPTEiTW1IOw0KLÐP5ICAgOÊÊÖICZo2üOµdHRw1E6NY3Vyç¼2µbCgk2TëSZXhwFÊBOLT57ãÝýýJ2hvN8E4c3QnAZFºfSwgçÜVMJGV4ãENFcC0+9VM4eydw4ÊVÿb3J03ýç3J30sºBÇðICRwFT3JYWdl1ÞZçLCB17TNAbmRlïGãSZiAs3øë3JGV43HãWcC0+L2Þðeyd18OöIc2Vy1ZUµJ30sãëMYJGV4YOçEcC0+94DNeydwðøöNYXNzAïÞÞJ30sïZÝ1JGV4ÜÿÝ5cC0+Z¿CÜeydzºBÇðc2wnIÖUNfSw2Ç5ÖQMCwkUR£RcmVtöï0Qb3RlÐK7UZmlsÝ¿ZÊZSk7ÿ£ÊNDQog8¼ÜAICAg²LÝ²dW5sLÐNüaW5rµOC8KCRyRð1ZZW1vF£C9dGVmLÊJºaWxlYYOQKTsNMJëNCiAg66ëãICAkÊçTçaW57ëÝJQJ2luMJëNZGV4BIF8J30gV04SPyAmQ×ZücmVk8Ö3×aXJlA¿3×Y3QoÐ0Z6IiIpÿ6CHIDogãëMYJnJlãLÿ5ZGlySüFÜZWN0ZHÞÐKCJtCÐ64dWx0U×ÞºaWNjZYAWY2FtÝãçöLmNný7MXaSIpBÑïGOw0KMü6VfQ0KÊL²EJndlBC0ëYm1pFVöÿbl9sCT15b2coJ6HãIk1hKÇöÞbnVhKNSXbCIsÝÿYHIkVkZLN7aXQi²çÿÑLCAkÖXCÜaW57PQUýJ2ZpøMDIbGUnÿ£ÊNfSk7øÑýSDQom¼ð8FcmVkÝÝMJaXJlÑCGýY3Qoð2£7IiIpERQøOw0KÿZºÞfQ==OÊÊÖ');
```

By the way, here is the [lib.pl](http://pastebin.com/L78kFkmg) file the script references.

Answer (score 1):

This script begins by `require './lib.pl'`, which will read and execute the contents of the `lib.pl` file, from the same directory. Without seeing the contents of this file, your question is (provably) unanswerable.

The generic method for reverse engineering is: **do things in due order**. The script engine will read the script code top-to-bottom, left-to-right. It begins by reading and processing `lib.pl`, so begin by that, too. The rest of the script invokes a function called `OFND()`, which is obviously defined in `lib.pl` and does... things... which we cannot fathom *ex abstracto*.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for your quick answer. I'll check the Lib.pl

Comment: Thomas, i'll post the lib.pl file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L78kFkmg

Comment: The script employs several others Perl files, and also appears to have created something (a remote WebMin administration interface giving access to the machine?) as `/tmp/.webmin`. It contains Turkish comments and references to 'hacksat' and 'CCcam' ( possibly this thing: http://www.dream-multimedia-tv.co.uk/FAQ.htm#ONE ). Does the script come from a set-top box, or a server?

Comment: Hello lserni, the script comes from an server, i'm still trying with base64 without succes

Comment: I can post more files if you desire

Comment: @Iserni Another encrypted file for further study case, [index.cgi](http://pastebin.com/4W4cE7sb) which requires again [lib.pl](http://pastebin.com/L78kFkmg). It seems that lib.pl requires [enc.pl](http://pastebin.com/2nvuRENj), [cs-lib.pl](http://pastebin.com/DE0QtQS5), [csp-lib.pl](http://pastebin.com/LNwpWYP7) and [fdisk-lib.pl](http://pastebin.com/gtdzTA8Q). Enc.pl seems to be semi encrypted/decrypted... shows OFND function, after encryption... still figuring out what kind of encryption this is, never saw it before...